# Reducing for loop overhead

Tags: c++, performance, iteration

I have a need to iterate through an amortization formula, which looks like this:

```
R = ( L * (r / m) ) / ( 1 - pow( (1 + (r / m)), (-1 * m * t ) );
```

I'm using a `for` loop for iteration, and incrementing the L (loan value) by 1 each time. The loop works just fine, but it did make me wonder about something else, which is the value (or lack thereof) in performing basic operations before a loop executes and then referencing those values through a variable. For example, I could further modify this function to look like

```
// outside for loop
amortization = (r/m)/(1 - pow( (1+(r/m)), (-1*m*t) ) )

// inside for loop
R = L * amortization
```

This way, instead of having to perform lots of math operations on every iteration of the loop, I can just reference the variable amount and perform a single operation.

What I'm wondering is how relevant is this? Is there any actual value in extracting these operations, or is the time saved so small that we're talking about a savings of milliseconds from a for loop that iterates approx. 200,000 times.  Follow up question: would extracting operations like this be worth it if I were doing more expensive operations like `sqrt`?

*(note: in case it matters, I'm asking about this specifically with c++ in mind)*

Comment: The compiler does this sort of thing anyway - try Google for 'loop invariant'.

Comment: Why not just see what the difference is yourself? I think experimentation is probably quicker than asking this question.

Comment: @Rooke I did try this and I wasn't seeing an performance difference. Apparently this is due to 'loop invariant code'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compilers would exercise an optimization technique here which is called **loop invariant code motion**. It does pretty much what you did manually, i.e. extracting a constant part of expression evaluated repeteadly in loop into a precomputed value stored in variable (or register). Hence it is not likely that you gain any performance by doing this yourself.

Of course if it's critical speed-wise, you should profile and/or review the assembly code produced by compiler in both cases.

Answer (score 2):

Compilers already move *loop invariant code* to the outside of the loop. This optimisation is known as "[Loop Invariant Code Motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop-invariant_code_motion)" or "Hoisting Invariants".

If you want to know how much it affects performance then the only way you are going to know is if you try. I would imagine that if you are doing this 200,000 times then it certainly could affect performance (if the compiler doesn't already do it for you).

Answer (score 2):

As others have mentioned, good compilers will do this sort of optimization automatically.  However...

First, `pow` is probably a library function, so your compiler might or might not know it is a "pure" function (i.e., that its behavior depends only on its arguments).  If not, it will be unable to perform this optimization, because for all it knows `pow` might print a message or something.

Second, I think factoring this expression out of the loop makes the code easier to understand, anyway.  The human reading your code can also factor out this expression "automatically", but why make them?  It just distracts them from your algorithm's flow.

So I would say to make this change regardless.

That said, if you really care about performance, get a decent profiler and do not worry about micro-optimizations until it tells you to.  Your priorities early on should be (a) use a decent algorithm and (b) implement it clearly.  And not in that order.

Comment: While I was curious about savings in speed, it was really more from an educational stand-point. As in, would there be any difference between how the compiler sees and executes the code, and would the difference be noticeable?

Comment: @Moses:  A good optimizing compiler that can prove `pow` is a pure function and that `r`, `m`, and `t` are constant within the loop will generate exactly the same code for both.  But such proofs can be harder than you might think.  For example, if `r` is a global and you call any (non-inline, non-pure) function within the loop, the compiler will not know that `r` does not change...  So it will not be able to lift the expression out of the loop.  For complex expressions, lifting them out by hand sometimes makes the code faster and usually makes it easier to read, IMO.

Comment: one last question, do you know if non-compiled languages like JavaScript are able to optimize invariant code? I did some googling and came up with nothing, but I'm pretty sure I remember reading somewhere that they did.

Comment: It depends on the interpreter.  Most "non-compiled languages" are actually "just-in-time compiled", and a "just-in-time" compiler can perform many of the same optimizations as any other.  I would not be surprised if the Javascript interpreter in Google Chrome, for instance, did some fancy things.  But I would still factor out the expressions myself anyway :-)

Comment: ++ If profiling shows much time is going into this, then clearly moving `pow` out of the loop wins big time. That said, I would never bet my shirt on a compiler being able to do that automatically, if it's just as easy for me to do it.

Answer (score 1):

When you have opimizations turned on then moving constant expressions outside of a loop is something that compilers are pretty good at doing on their own, so this might buy you no speed up anyway.

But if it doesn't this looks like a reasonable thing to try, and then time it IF this is actually taking longer than you require.